# prolog get a list of numbers from list of wildcards and numbers

Tags: prolog

I wonder if it's possible to do something like the following in prolog

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,_,_,7].
```

i want to do something like

```
getElements(L, R)
```

that returns
    R = [1,2,3,4,5,7]

and ignore the wildcards in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Prolog has [library(apply)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29), you can write

```
getElements(L, R) :- 
   include(nonvar, L, R).
```

or, a bit more compact

```
getElements(L, R) :- 
   exclude(var, L, R).
```

Otherwise, this should be a working predicate:

```
getElements([], []).
getElements([H|T], [H|R]) :-
  nonvar(H), !,
  getElements(T, R).
getElements([_|T], R) :-
  getElements(T, R).
```

**edit** as highlighted by @false, the latter getElements/2 is buggy, due to matching with the anonymous variable in last clause. Here a correction

```
getElements([], []).
getElements([H|T], R) :-
  var(H), !,
  getElements(T, R).
getElements([H|T], [H|R]) :-
  getElements(T, R).
```

Comment: `getElements([a],[])` now succeeds.